# Pandas Applying multiple greater than and less than grouping rows by specific column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am creating 3 pandas dataframes based off of one original pandas dataframe.  I have calculated standard deviations from the norm.

```
#Mean
stats_over_29000_mean = stats_over_29000['count'].mean().astype(int)
```

152542

```
#STDS
stats_over_29000_count_between_std = stats_over_29000_std - stats_over_29000_mean
```

54313

```
stats_over_29000_first_std = stats_over_29000_mean + stats_over_29000_count_between_std
```

206855

```
stats_over_29000_second_std = stats_over_29000_first_std + stats_over_29000_count_between_std
```

261168

```
stats_over_29000_third_std = stats_over_29000_second_std + stats_over_29000_count_between_std
```

315481

This works to get all rows from df under 2 stds

```
#Select all rows where count is less than 2 standard deviations 
stats_under_2_stds = stats_over_29000[stats_over_29000['count'] < stats_over_29000_second_std]
```

Next I would like to select all rows from df where >=2 stds and less than 3 stds

I have tried:

```
stats_2_and_over_under_3_stds = stats_over_29000[stats_over_29000['count'] >= stats_over_29000_second_std < stats_over_29000_third_std]
```

and

```
stats_2_and_over_under_3_stds = stats_over_29000[stats_over_29000['count'] >= stats_over_29000_second_std && < stats_over_29000_third_std]
```

But neither seem to work.

Comment: Try `stats_2_and_over_under_3_stds = ((stats_over_29000[stats_over_29000['count'] >= stats_over_29000_second_std) & (stats_over_29000[stats_over_29000['count'] < stats_over_29000_third_std])).sum()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is how you filter on df with 2 conditions :**

- init `df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[1,3],[1,5],[1,8]],columns=['A','B'])`
- operation : `res = df[(df['B']<8) & (df['B']>2)]`
- result :

  ```
     A  B
  1  1  3
  2  1  5
  ```

**In your case :**

```
stats_2_and_over_under_3_stds = stats_over_29000[(stats_over_29000['count'] >= stats_over_29000_second_std) & (stats_over_29000['count'] < stats_over_29000_third_std)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Pandas now has the `Series.between(left, right, inclusive=True)`, that allows both [both comparisons at the same time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html).

In your case:

```
stats_2_and_over_under_3_stds = \
  stats_over_29000[(stats_over_29000['count'].between(
  stats_over_29000_second_std, stats_over_29000_third_std)]
```

Comment: Love it @Sylvain thanks for posting, learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

The `loc` function allow you to apply multiple conditions to filter a dataframe in a very concise syntax. I'm putting in "column of interest" as I do not know the column name where you have the values stored. Alternatively if the column of interest is the index, you could just write a condition directly as `(stats_over_29000 > 261168)` inside the loc function.

```
    stats_over_29000.loc[(stats_over_29000('column of interest') > 261168) &\
 (stats_over_29000('column of interest') < 315481)]
```